# Can't use column name list to create SQLite View in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, anaconda

I've created a database and am able to create a simple view using the following command:

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS monthly_terminals (year, month) AS
  SELECT reportYear, reportMonth FROM osMonthlyTerminals
```

This command works just fine if I paste into the SQLite Manager plugin on FireFox:

[image]

I then drop this view and try to use the exact same command in the following Python 3 code to create this view...

```
import sqlite3
db_name = "../data/OsReportMerchants.sqlite"
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS monthly_terminals (year, month) AS SELECT reportYear, reportMonth FROM osMonthlyTerminals")
```

... but I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

More specifically, it looks like this in ipython:

[image]

Yes, I know I should be parameterizing this and I have tried to do so, but keep running into this same snag.

I look at this:  https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html  and it says that column lists are supported in 3.9 and later, so I updated to version 3.13 of sqlite3 and still ran into this issue.

When I remove the column list and use this:

```
import sqlite3
db_name = "../data/OsReportMerchants.sqlite"
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS monthly_terminals AS SELECT reportYear, reportMonth FROM osMonthlyTerminals")
```

it works fine.  Not sure why it works in one context and not in the other.

Answer (score 1):

Python has its own copy of the SQLite library (see `sqlite3.sqlite_version`).

If the latest Python version does not have a recent enough version of SQLite, the only way to update it would be to recompile Python, or use some other DB driver like [APSW](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/).

Comment: When I do a  conda list, it shows sqlite 3.13.0.  When I do sqlite3.version (after importing sqlite3) from the python shell, it says 2.6.0.  This seems confusing to me (maybe because I'm relatively new to Python).  So it looks like the FireFox plugin is using a newer version and my Python code is using the older version. Is that what is going on?

Comment: See the first sentence of my answer.